# Prevent adding locale string for default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to prevent rails adding locale string to links if default locale is selected.For example, if I go directly to example.com, link generated by helper shoudn't be example.com/en/orders (it should be example.com/orders).

My application_controlelr.rb contains

```
 def default_url_options
      { locale: I18n.locale }
 end
```

which I assume adds locale to links, and routes.rb

```
scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|es/ do
    resources :orders
end
```

So, is there a way to stop that ?

Comment: Yes - remove those from your code!

Comment: With default_url_options removed I get Routing error...

Comment: Well, the whole point is to have links in the format domain.com/(:locale)/somepage  and If I remove those lines from routes.rb i won't have that.I only want to disable this behaviour for default locale, set in I18n.default_locale, so when open example.com/, helpers don't generate links with the locale inside them

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Only way I can see it work is if you copy all the routes to another scope with no `:locale` in path and default `:locale` set to en (or es)